# Pandas: Alter a column by condition using other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe here (sorry for the bad example)

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Alpha": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Beta": ["C", "D", "E", "F", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "Value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 1],
})
```

I want that for every Alpha == A, the "Value" of the rows with "Beta"="D" should be the value of "Beta="F" multiplied by a random number and a scalar.

```
mask = (df['Alpha'] == 'A')
df.loc[mask & (df['Beta'] == 'D'), 'Value'] = df.loc[mask & (df['Beta'] == 'F'), 'Value'] * 0.5 * random.uniform(0.95, 1.05)
```

Both loc functions return a series of equal length (also in other more advanced examples), but in the end, the Value becomes NaN everywhere. This is also the case if I remove the scalar.

Any ideas how to easily solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). For the random number take advantage of [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) (or any other function depending on the wanted distribution):

```
import numpy as np

scalar = 0.5

mask_D = df['Beta'].eq('D')
mask_F = df['Beta'].eq('F')

df.loc[mask_D, 'Value'] = (df.loc[mask_D, 'Alpha']
                            .map(df[mask_F].set_index('Alpha')['Value'])
                            .mul(scalar*np.random.uniform(0.95, 1.05, size=mask_D.sum()))
                         )
```

Output:

```
  Alpha Beta  Value
0     A    C      1
1     A    D      2
2     A    E      3
3     A    F      4
4     B    C      7
5     B    D      2
6     B    E      5
7     B    F      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code attempts to assign a `pd.Series` to a single cell of column `Value`, while it's expected to assign a single value respectively (according to your intention). Access raw `values` as shown below:

```
df.loc[mask & (df['Beta'] == 'D'), 'Value'] = (df.loc[mask & (df['Beta'] == 'F'), 'Value']
                                               * 0.5 * random.uniform(0.95, 1.05)).values
```

---

Sample output:

```
  Alpha Beta     Value
0     A    C  1.000000
1     A    D  1.958938
2     A    E  3.000000
3     A    F  4.000000
4     B    C  7.000000
5     B    D  2.000000
6     B    E  5.000000
7     B    F  1.000000
```

Comment: I was just short of one ".values"? :O

Comment: @Hemmelig, in your case you're reassigning "one-to-one" (`A-D` to `A-F`), so yes

Comment: If you have a missing F or B, this will however trigger a ValueError. And if you have one missing F and one missing B in a different group this will mismatch the values. Using the underlying numpy array is a powerful tool but you need to be sure of what you're doing ;)